# Нежелательный отступ при отображении на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

При уменьшении экрана появляется нежелательный отступ и текст как будто выпадает из контейнера. Как исправить? Использую библиотеку Bootstrap. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/*HEADER*/

.contact {
  background-color: #eceff1;
}
.phone {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.phone p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.phone img {
  width: 30px;
}
/*Large Devices, Wide Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .logo img {
    width: 30px;
  }
}
/*Medium Devices, Desctops */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {}
/* Small Devises, Tablets */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .phone {
    padding: 3px 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  .phone img {
    width: 20px;
  }
  .contact .logo img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluide text-center contact">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 phone logo">
      <img src="css/img/icon_agua.png" hspace="10"><span>AAAAAAAAAA</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 phone">
      <img src="css/img/vodaone.png" class="img-circle" hspace="10"><span>066111111111</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 phone">
      <img src="css/img/Kyivstar.png" class="img-circle" hspace="10"><span>097111111111</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Пробывали `col-md-4 col-sm-4 phone logo` добавьте класс `col-xs-12`?